# Alternative ways in counting satisfied random computation of n times from sc.parallelize(range(0, n))

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The code below finds the approximation value of a PI through parallelising and filtering. The approach requires me to pass `itr` as an argument inside the `calc_points_in_circ(itr)` to work. The issue is, the variable `itr` value is unused and has no intentions to be part of the calculation logic. How can this be rewritten without any unused variables, and still make use of PySpark parallelisation?

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
import random

sc = SparkContext("local", "PI Approx")
spark = SparkSession(sc)

pointsInCircle = 0
n = 1_000_000


def calc_points_in_circ(itr):
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()

    # Pythagorean theorem; c = math.sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
    distance = (x*x + y*y) ** 0.5

    return distance < 1


rdd = sc.parallelize(range(0, n))
pointsInCircle = rdd.filter(calc_points_in_circ).count()

pi = 4 * pointsInCircle / n

print(f"PI approximation: {pi:.3f}")
```

Comment: You can replace `itr` with `_`: `def calc_points_in_circ(_):`